# For `America`, why doesn't OpenStreetmap return the country `USA` at all? How to add such an alias to the Nominatim server?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

As per title,
I do not understand why searching for `America` does not return the country `USA` at all, even up to the top 50 results.

What can I do to change this (I think we should return the country `USA` at least within the top 30 results)? Is there some alias I can add to the database?

Openstreetmap API: https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=america

Nominatim search API: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=america&format=jsonv2&addressdetails=1&namedetails=1&dedupe=1&extratags=1&limit=50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because so far no one thought about "America" as an alternative name for the United States of America in English. E.g. you got the colloquial name "Amerika" added for some languages as a place name or alternative name, but so far not "America".

So if you do think that "America" is used in English as an alternative for the USA, you might add the alt_name:en=America tag to this relation:

https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/148838

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I have added the alternative name. However, when I search for "America" on `openstreetmap`, it still does not show up in one of the top few search results. Any idea how long does it take before the Nominatim service rebuilds the index, taking into account such alt names? Thanks!

Comment: 6 hours later I'm getting what you tried to achieve: the USA relation is first while searching for America. Currently the nominatim instances run by OSMF update the data in minutes but twice a day the update process lags by up to two hours, see here: https://munin.openstreetmap.org/nominatim-day.html (data import lag for different nominatim instances).